# Is it possible to have a Windows form that is both semi-transparent AND fully transparent?

Tags: vb6

I'd like to have a form that is semi transparent but has a section that *more* transparent (or fully transparent, i.e. "invisible")

So, imagine a semi transparent form with a rectangle in the middle that is fully transparent (kinda like  doughnut)

Comment: VB6 has "Thunder Forms."  The "Windows Form" thing is a .Net GUI widget framework.  Are you asking about VB6 or .Net here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is VB 6, just take a look at [this thread from VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?695393-Here-s-How-to-Make-a-Form-With-a-HOLE-in-it).

For convenience sake, I have pasted the code here:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function CreateRectRgn Lib "gdi32" (ByVal X1 As Long, ByVal Y1 As Long, ByVal X2 As Long, ByVal Y2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CombineRgn Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestRgn As Long, ByVal hSrcRgn1 As Long, ByVal hSrcRgn2 As Long, ByVal nCombineMode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowRgn Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hRgn As Long, ByVal bRedraw As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Sub Form_Resize()
 Const RGN_DIFF = 4
 Dim outer_rgn As Long
 Dim inner_rgn As Long
 Dim combined_rgn As Long
 Dim wid As Single
 Dim hgt As Single
 Dim border_width As Single
 Dim title_height As Single
If WindowState = vbMinimized Then Exit Sub

' Create the regions.
wid = ScaleX(Width, vbTwips, vbPixels)
hgt = ScaleY(Height, vbTwips, vbPixels)
outer_rgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, wid, hgt)

border_width = (wid - ScaleWidth) / 2
title_height = hgt - border_width - ScaleHeight
inner_rgn = CreateRectRgn( _
    wid * 0.25, hgt * 0.25, _
    wid * 0.75, hgt * 0.75)
' Subtract the inner region from the outer.
combined_rgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0)
CombineRgn combined_rgn, outer_rgn, _
    inner_rgn, RGN_DIFF

' Restrict the window to the region.
SetWindowRgn hWnd, combined_rgn, True
DeleteObject combined_rgn
DeleteObject inner_rgn
DeleteObject outer_rgn
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, there's a BUG in that code:  border_width = (wid - ScaleWidth) / 2
title_height = hgt - border_width - ScaleHeight. Need to CONVERT  Scalewidth and *Height to Pixels.

Comment: border_width = (wid - frm.ScaleX(frm.ScaleWidth, vbTwips, vbPixels)) / 2
title_height = hgt - border_width - frm.ScaleY(frm.ScaleHeight, vbTwips, vbPixels)